# Not able to create a connection to Janus to define the schema

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra-3.0, janusgraph, tinkerpop3

Not able to create a connection to Janus to define the schema.

```
JanusGraph graph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cql")//.set("storage.cql.keyspace", "janusgraph")
                .set("storage.hostname", "url").open();
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find implementation class: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:75)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:530)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:494)
```

Able to do normal tinkerpop gremlin query with the following config

```
@Bean
public Cluster cluster() {
    return Cluster.build()
            .addContactPoint(dbUrl)
            .port(dbPort)
            .serializer(new GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1())
            .maxConnectionPoolSize(5)
            .maxInProcessPerConnection(1)
            .maxSimultaneousUsagePerConnection(10)
            .create();
}

@Bean
public GraphTraversalSource g(Cluster cluster) throws Exception {
    //return traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster));
     return traversal().withRemote("conf/remote-graph.properties");
}
```

Want to define the schema during the application start up, Trying to use `openManagement`

Answer (score 1):

When writing a java application using janusgraph, you can choose between [embedding janusgraph in your application](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/tree/master/janusgraph-examples/example-cql)  or [connecting to a janusgraph server](https://docs.janusgraph.org/interactions/connecting/java/). Your code suggests you are attempting the embedded option, so you can start from the example in the provided link.